# python unpack replace php unpack

Tags: php, python

php code

```
$body = unpack("Lcmd/Lstatus/a*username", $body_string);
```

I want use python code replace this line. how to do?

> struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 17

```
cnt = unpack('LLs', body_string)
```